# highcharts cannot panning on mobile browser

Tags: android, mobile, highcharts, panning

it working on PC's browser, but not working on android's chrome browser(on my nexus 7 ver 4.3).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUSyF/80/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            panning: true
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1#', '2#', '3#', '4#', '5#', '6#', '7#', '8#', '9#', '10#', '11#', '12#', '13#', '14#', '15#', '16#', '17#', '18#', '19#', '20#', '21#', '22#', '23#', '24#', '25#', '26#', '27#', '28#', '29#', '30#', '31#', '32#', '33#', '34#', '35#', '36#', '37#', '38#', '39#', '40#', '41#', '42#', '43#', '44#', '45#', '46#', '47#', '48#', '49#', '50#', '51#', '52#', '53#', '54#', '55#', '56#', '57#', '58#', '59#', '60#', '61#', '62#', '63#', '64#', '65#', '66#', '67#', '68#', '69#', '70#', '71#', '72#', '73#', '74#', '75#', '76#', '77#', '78#', '79#', '80#', '81#', '82#', '83#', '84#', '85#', '86#', '87#', '88#'],
            min: 0,
            max:18
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
            liveRedraw: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            max: 10
        },
        series: [{
            data: [0, 0, 8, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}]
    });
});
```

Comment: I opened your example in the Chrome browser (android) on 4.3 and 4.4 (nexus / samsung s3) and in all cases, charts works properly. How we can replicate your issue?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I test chrome(34.0.1847.114) on 4.3 nexus 7 and IE10 on Lumia 920 both cannot panning. The highcharts's owner test on iOS were also. I created an issue on highcharts's github. [issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2903)

Comment: Thanks for this, so please stay on track with github thread.